# Class level Route in asp.net with variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have a class level `Route` that ends in a variable? 
Ex:

```
[Route("api/{carType}")]
public class CarController : Controller
{
  ..rest of class
}
```

and if so how would you access that variable?

Or am I just thinking about this completely wrong? I have a couple of objects that all derive from the same abstract class and right now I have a different controller for each but they are all the same practically. I think it would be possible to have generic methods to handle everything but not sure the best way to interpret what type the object actually is.

Ex:

```
[Route("api/{carType}")]
public class CarController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet()]
     public IActionResult GetCars()
     {
        IActionResult result; 
        switch(carType){
            case "Ford":
               result = myService.GetCars<Ford>();
               break;
            case "Toyota":
               result = myService.GetCars<Toyota>();
               break;
            ....
        }
        return result; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always do it as in following example:

```
[RoutePrefix("customers/{customerId}")]
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    // GET customers/1/orders
    [Route("orders")]
    public IEnumerable<Order> Get(int customerId) 
    { 
      ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have done this many times. You would create a route which maps to a generic action that takes the class name and then using reflection, invokes whatever method you want on that action.

Comment: I see, aren't you able to just add carType as a parameter for GetCars? Like "public IActionResult GetCars(string carType)"?

Comment: But doesn't seem that clean. Might rethink how I'm going about it